# Upload large files to S3 using Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I have a file with a size of more than 4MB uploaded to `S3` while the user registers in my app.

Here are my ways to upload:

1. upload directly to `S3` without any `job queue` as follow:

```
$data = $request->all();

if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
    Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads/user/', $image, 'public');
    $data['image'] = $image->hashName();
}

$user = User::create($data);
```

With the above approach, it takes `3 to 4` seconds to upload!

2. I said let's try to create a `job queue` to make the request faster, so my controller is changed to

```
$data = $request->all();

$user = User::create($data);

if ($file = $request->file('image')) {
    $file->move(public_path() . '/temporary_images', $imageName = uniqid());
    $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    dispatch(new RegisterJob($user, $imageName, $extension));
}
```

Then in my job:

```
class RegisterJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $user, $imageName, $extension;

    public function __construct($user, $imageName, $extension)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->imageName = $imageName;
        $this->extension = $extension;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $imageName = $this->imageName . '.' . $this->extension;

        $imagePath = public_path() . '/temporary_images/' . $this->imageName;

        if (Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads/user/' . $imageName, fopen($imagePath, 'r+'), 'public')) {

            $this->user->update(['image' => $imageName]);

            File::delete($imagePath);
        }
    }
}
```

With this approach, it takes `10 to 15` seconds to upload the file with 4MB!!!

What is the best approach to upload an image using job and s3!?

Comment: How do you measure the timing of file uploading? Are you sure your job is running asynchronously? If job is not asynchronous, it only adds overhead comparing to direct uploading.

Comment: @IliaYatsenko I measure the timing from the postman, so my problem with the second way is when uploading the file to my server, not `S3` because I stopped the queue running and it takes a lot of time to upload to my server!

Comment: Ok, so if the most time-consuming part is `$file->move(..)` part, maybe it is better to stay with first approach and upload directly to s3? Or you could change the second approach by moving this line into `dispatchAfterResponse`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#dispatching-after-the-response-is-sent-to-browser

Comment: @IliaYatsenko Does`dispatchAfterResponse` work with the first way? or I have to use `job` with it?

Comment: Did you try to use mount tools to use S3 as a drive in your system? It will sync automatically. I used similar tools in Google Cloud (gsfuse) and it works well. Maybe that we help you:
https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/amazon-s3-as-a-file-system

Comment: @user16390519, I meant that you could try to wrap the time-consuming code (moving uploaded file and uploading to s3) into the dispatchAfterResponse, so that it will be executed after the response was sent to the client. When you do that you can upload directly into s3 or dispatch the job, but this will not matter because client has already got the response.

Comment: @IliaYatsenko but I can not pass image to the job I should upload it to my server first then upload to S3

Comment: See example in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/68622032/6051839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
$data = $request->all();

if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
    dispatch(function () use ($image) {
        Storage::disk('s3')->put('uploads/user/', $image, 'public');
    })->afterResponse();
}

$user = User::create($data);
```

or:

```
$data = $request->all();

if ($image = $request->file('image')) {
    dispatch(function () use ($image) {
        $image->move(public_path() . '/temporary_images', $imageName = uniqid());
        $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        dispatch(new RegisterJob($user, $imageName, $extension));
    })->afterResponse();
}

$user = User::create($data);
```